# How to View asp.net-mvc Build in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I apologize for the remedial question. I accidentally closed the tab in Visual Studio that allows me to view the actual application (the one that loads by default when you create a new project). How do I bring this back up?

I've tried closing and re-opening the project, going through solution explorer in its entirety, and scanning every information source I can get my hands on. Thank you for your advice (and patience)!

Comment: Do you mean Page Inspector? - View -> Other Windows -> Page inspector

Comment: Not seeing that as an option, do I have to be in a specific file?

Comment: What do you mean by the view of actual application? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Like the interface, the same thing I get if I run it in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want  get the interface, that if you run your application it in a browser. On the panel open your browsers and choice **Browse With**:

[image]

in window choice **Internal Web Browser** and click **Browse**

[image]

If you want view your build anytime  in internal browser - **Set as Default**.
Sorry for my English.